# Intercept link clicks in WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to intercept link clicks in `WKWebView` and depending on the URL, either open the link in an external browser or load it in the web view as usual.

The first approach that comes to mind is overriding `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` in `WKNavigationDelegate`, but this gets called even when the "virtual address bar" (`url` property of the web view) doesn't change, for example various tracking and ad requests.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to intercept all http requests (e.g. AJAX) from your HTML page, not only clicks on links?

Comment: Any request that would change WKWebView.url. This should only happen on clicks on links in my case, but in theory it can also be triggered by javascript.

Answer (score 4):

This scenario is why `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)` includes a `WKNavigationAction` argument, which provides information about what triggered the request. The `navigationType` property of that class is an enumeration with possible values including `linkActivated`, `formSubmitted`, and others to tell you why you're being asked to decide policy. Check that to see what triggered the request, and make your decision based on that.